# Make application title bold

Tags: gnome, 20.04, fonts

The menu in the top bar that shows the application name is very slim looking.  I would like to make it bold.  How would I go about doing this?

My gnome-shell.css is in this dropbox link:

[gnome-shell.css](https://www.dropbox.com/s/atz4zfrk7y78phe/gnome-shell.css?dl=0)

Comment: You need to edit css file of gnome-shell theme being used.

Comment: How would I edit it.  What would I put into it.

Comment: Can you share the theme file?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Ok I have down loaded the file. Will get back in couple of hrs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the `gnome-shell.css` file, at line number 2989 find below content.

```
#panel .panel-button {
  -natural-hpadding: 8px;
  -minimum-hpadding: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  transition-duration: 150ms;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

For testing purpose I have changed the font-weight to noraml and edited some other related to Activities.

[image]

The font-weight field is responsible, however I guess you have many extensions installed and enabled. One of the extension is overwriting this. Turn on extensions one by one and find out which extension is causing this. Provide the link to that extension for further improvement.